# class 'MainActivity' Implements error for Detector

Tags: java, android, affdex-sdk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WTDw.png)

I have finished to settle the manifest and gradle as the tutorial on affdex-android sdk, but when i am trying to declare the implements in public MyActivity, always become error

class 'MainActivity' must either declared abstract or implements abstract method ..

Comment: It can happen only when you have not implemented `onCreate()` method in your activity or when you implement any interface in your activity and don't implement its method(s).

Your error says you have not implemented methods of the interfaces you have implemented in your activity

Comment: thanks a lot  @Apurva now fixed